# Can you ask for a review on code of a self-created language?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

If one were to create their own language and documentation for the language, could they ask for a review on code they have written in their language as long as they provided a link or inline documentation?

Comment: I'm not certain this is a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, you can, I've done it myself [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86642/notbf-a-brainfuck-ish-like-languagel)

Comment: The short answer is, "So long as there's a compiler/interpreter". Otherwise, it's hypothetical code.

Comment: @RubberDuck That post seems to be asking about posting code for an interpreter to a made up language. This is about posting code in that language itself, where the code might be FizzBuzz, for example.

Comment: Perhaps not a duplicate question then, but I believe the answer there covers this one too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The asker would have do more than provide a link to documentation or inline documentation.

There needs to be an existing compiler or interpreter for the language.  There needs to be a way for potential reviewers to actually run the code.

If the code cannot be compiled/interpreted and ran, then the code is nothing but a special syntax of pseudo-code.